# Issue settings value to deque pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, deque

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

void insertValues(deque<float*> mydeque)
{
    *mydeque.at(0)=12;
}

void initArray(deque<float*> mydeque, float* values)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        mydeque.push_back(values+i);
}

int main ()
{
    float values[3];
    deque<float*> mydeque;
    initArray(mydeque,values);

    insertValues(mydeque); //Gives out of range - memory error

    cout<<values<<" "<<values+1<<" " <<values[0]<<endl;
    values[0]=5;
    cout<<values<<" "<<values+1<<" " <<values[0]<<endl;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, i bump into memory issues on calling insertValues() function and it gives out of range error but i don't know why that happens because the deque has the correct addresses which i verified.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a `deque<float*>` instead of `deque<float>`?  Why the usage of pointers?  Looks like you're purposefully trying to cause issues with your code.

Comment: In my case, the values i deal with are modified by other functions or threads so was not sure what else to do other than use pointer to float. (The above code is just a sample that i try before actually implementing features in the main code base.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here.

```
void initArray(deque<float*> mydeque, float* values)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        mydeque.push_back(values+i);
}
```

`mydeque` is going to be a copy of whatever you passed, `mydeque` was filled and later destroyed. The originally passed parameter remains untouched.
Modify it to take the parameter by reference...

```
void initArray(deque<float*>& mydeque, float* values)
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        mydeque.push_back(new float(values+i);
}
```

---

Though your code will work as it is, but you should not use a `std::deque` of pointers to `float`. Its way too fragile and its less performant in time and memory. Prefer to use integral types by value.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In my case, the values i deal with are floats and they are modified by other functions or threads so was not sure what else to do other than use pointer to float. (The above code is just a sample that i try before actually implementing features in the main code base.)

Comment: Also, i wanted to know on using floats the access time was really high and why do you think it would be more efficient using integral types? What is the logic behind that?